# EHCI_HCD resets interfere with USB transfers

Tags: usb, vaio, reset

So I have this extremely annoying problem and would love some help. Thanks in advance. First off I'm using a Vaio Z series Laptop, 2.4 GHZ, 4 GB DDR3 RAM. I am on Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit at the moment. The problem started when I did a clean install of 11.10. I encountered multiple bugs including the one I'm going to describe below. I went back to 11.04 and some how I have the same bug in 11.04 as well now. I did NOT have this bug before.

Basically, when I connect my android phone to the computer and try to transfer music to it via a USB cable in rhythmbox, the transfers are extremely slow and after awhile it crashes and I get errors. My phones SD card is unmounted and unable to mount again till I yank the battery out. `dmesg` gives me the following output.

```
    [   14.103288] usbcore: registered new interface driver qcserial
    [   46.080145] usb 2-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
    [   46.795743] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
    [   46.830958] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
    [   46.831135] scsi6 : usb-storage 2-1:1.0
    [   46.831758] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
    [   46.831760] USB Mass Storage support registered.
    [   68.119351] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, address 3
    [   68.900055] usb 2-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
    [   69.065239] scsi7 : usb-storage 2-1:1.0
    [  329.240062] usb 2-1: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
    [  339.570085] usb 2-1: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
    [  355.900067] usb 2-1: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
    [  356.240041] usb 2-1: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
    [  366.570066] usb 2-1: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
    [  401.750816] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, address 4
```

I thought maybe there was something wrong with my SD card so I bought a new 16 GB class 4 card but the same problem occurs. If I use the MicroSD with an adapter in the card reader the transfer speeds start off at 20 mb and then slow down to 1 mb.

I don't know what to do. I searched all over the Ubuntu forums but didn't come up with any solutions. I can confirm that I didn't have this problem before. Did an update break something? Is my ECHI driver broken due to an update? Is this a hardware problem? If its a kernel issue how come it wasn't there before but only appeared after i went to 11.10 and then back to 11.04. Thanks for all your help guys.

Answer (score 2):

If you really did not experience the problem before, it may be either a problem with the updated kernel or a hardware problem (with either the USB controller or the phone).

The first one seems unlikely to me, but you can check whether this is the case by downgrading your kernel to the version you had before in 11.04 ; for the second suggestion, check the following link :

http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_USB_2.0 .

Basically there is a good chance you'll be still able to use the USB connection if you'll drop down the USB 2.0 support, although it will give you the painful 12 mbit/sec, i.e about one Mb per second ; but it would probably be rather stable. *If the phone is the only device that brings you the problem, I would have simply stayed with USB 1.* for it.*

Another hypothesis would be that you have earlier used a 32-bit version of Ubuntu 11.04 and the bug appeared when you have switched to a 64-bit version .

Then I suggest you to try a 32-bit LiveCD and see if the problem persists .

PS. Here is an article explaining the procedure of unbinding the driver ( the spam protection engine prevents me from giving more links at once ) ) :

http://lwn.net/Articles/143397/